# Artifacts showing when modifying a custom QGraphicsItem

Tags: qt, repaint, artifacts, visual-artifacts

I'm currently developping a small vector drawing program in wich you can create lines and modify them after creation (those lines are based on a custom QGraphicsItem). For instance, the picture below shows what happens when the leftmost (marked yellow) point of the line is dragged to the right of the screen, effectively lengthening the line :

[image: Figure1]

Everything works fine when the point is moved slowly, however, when moved rapidly, some visual artifacts appear :

[image]

The piece of code I'm using to call for a repaint is located in the `mouseMoveEvent` redefined method, which holds the following lines of code :

```
QRectF br = boundingRect();
x2 = static_cast<int>(event->scenePos().x()-x());
y2 = static_cast<int>(event->scenePos().y()-y());
update(br);
```

There's apparently no problem with my `boundingRect` definition, since adding `painter->drawRect(boundingRect())` in the `paint` method shows this :

[image]

And there are also no problem when the line is simply moved (flag `QGraphicsItem::ItemIsMovable` is set), even rapidly.

Does anyone know what is happening here ? My guess is that `update` is not being called immediately hence `mouseMoveEvent` can be called multiple times before a repaint occurs, maybe canceling previous calls ? I'm not sure.

Of course the easy fix is to set the viewport mode of the `QGraphicsView` object holding the line to `QGraphicsView::FullViewportUpdate)`, but that is ugly (and slow).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without seeing the full function for how you're updating the line, I would guess that you've omitted to call [prepareGeometryChange()](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qgraphicsitem.html#prepareGeometryChange) before updating the bounding rect of the items.

As the docs state: -

> *Prepares the item for a geometry change. **Call this function before changing the bounding rect of an item to keep QGraphicsScene's index up to date.***